# how to write insert stored procedure when tablename and columnnames are unknown?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, insert

i want to write a **stored procedure** in `SQL server` that will `insert` records to database in which i want to pass **table-name** and **column-names** with their **values** as **arguments** to the stored procedure.

i am using asp.net three-tier technology if that helps.

if it's impossible than please tell me some alternatives.
thanks in advance

Comment: That's not really the SQL way. Queries tend to be about *specific* tables and *specific* columns, and there's no way for a single query to change that. Your only real option is to generate a query dynamically. As to "tell me some alternatives", it depends on what your actual requirements are. Is "stop trying to abstract things that should actually be concrete" a valid alternative?

Comment: @miko1 Without knowing the no. of Columns and datatype of Columns how can you insert

Comment: array ? insert into set ? like we do in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer is **"Don't Do That!"**

A relational database is best used for modelling.... relationships and to do that you need to have bounds and a design about what data you are going to store. That means that you (or your ORM) will know what the underlying tables look like.

If you want a place to simply throw objects at then think about using a nosql document store like MongoDB instead.

Comment: that's what i am doing now,i figured that's not the way things work in sql-server and asp.net three tier tech

Comment: This is advice, not an answer. Belongs in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Build your SQL in a NVARCHAR dynamically, and pass it to stored procedure sp_executesql:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
-- build your SQL in the NVARCHAR

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: @miko1 Based on your question, that's the best answer I can give. You would build the SQL dynamically in your stored procedure, and pass the SQL to the stored procedure `sp_executesql` to execute it.

Comment: you mean passing the sql query to stored proc which'll do the job of executing it right ?

Comment: @miko1 If you have the SQL, why not execute it against your database right away? What I explained is for your specific question: pass the table name and column name to the stored procedure, which will then dynamically build the SQL to execute whatever you want to do in the SQL. If you can build the SQL in your middle-tier, you should execute it against your database using the libraries you have at your disposal. It would be overhead to pass the SQL to a stored procedure, only to have it executed there.

Comment: but it's three-tier asp.net :(

Comment: and they say you must write stored proc that'll handle db management but writing lots of stored procedure doesn't seem good way to do this

Comment: @miko1 Well I don't know anything about ASP.NET, only about sql-server and software architecture in general. None of the tags mention ASP.NET or anything relating to tiers other than the database tier. I can't imagine why your middle-tier would not allow you to generate the SQL dynamically, which you then execute against your database. Perhaps you should do some research on how to generate SQL on your middle-tier. If that is impossible, you can try take my simple sketch as a basis.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in theory but I’m afraid that’s not really the best solution.

Issues with this approach is that you don’t know many parameters upfront such as column names, how many column names exist, what is their type and such.

This means that you would have to pass parameters as some default type for example nvarchar and then convert this type to specific column type which can lead to performance and other issues.

I’d suggest you try using [Entity framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or some other ORM tool to handle inserts for you.